# Uploading an image using an HTTPS link fails

Tags: bug, images, uploader

If you click the image uploading via the link, you cannot upload HTTPS files it seems, because I know jpegs are valid image formats that stack-exchange accepts.

There is a workaround by just clicking the Drag and Drop and pasting the https link there, which works fine.. but the link was never fixed for that I assume.

[image: 1]